# Are rest api query parameters secure when sending via HTTPS?

Tags: c#, api, rest, wcf, authentication

I have the following rest api method exposed

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetStuff?userName={userName}&password={password}&howMany={howMany}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Things[] GetStuff(string userName, string password, int howMany);
```

Is sending the username and password as part of the query string secure via https or is there a better way of authentication?

Comment: urls are stored in web server logs, browser history, ect. If you think that is secure, then you have your answer... There is always a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they aren't. As mentioned in the comment, if someone steals your logs, they have access to all the query parameters. (in your case, sensitive information).

The query parameters are (properly) used for idempotent requests (like `GET`) to filter your result set.

The header values on the other hand are safe. That's why we usually send authentication/authorization headers and not query parameters.

Check [authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) for an example of this.

> The HTTP Authorization request header contains the credentials to authenticate a user agent with a server, usually, but not necessarily, after the server has responded with a 401 Unauthorized status and the WWW-Authenticate header.